How to change batteries in a coast G36 flashlight
I have unscrewed the bottom and the only thing there was the button that turns it on and off. I've tried the top and it only adjust the lighting. How do I get to the battery compartment?

A picture showing with the bottom off might help.  Good chance you remove the button(on/off) also.  The bottom cover is there to prevent the insides from falling out in most flashlights.

You'll have to try a little harder to unscrew the tailcap, which is the piece that extends from the on/off button to the first parting line.

A pair of leather gloves may give you a better grip. The instructions say:

You'll find the full instruction sheet here (pdf).
